getchar() and space-character
I am experimenting with the getchar() function. Can someone please explain why every time I finish an input line with a space and then press Enter, the input window skips a line and then I have to press Enter again for the code to proceed.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 6 //+1 space for the 0

int main()
{
    char array[MAX_SIZE] = { 0 };
    char ch = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF
              && ch != '\n'
              // && ch != ' '
              && i < MAX_SIZE - 1)
        {
            if (islower(ch))
                ch = toupper(ch);
            else if (isupper(ch))
                ch = tolower(ch);

            while (ch == ' ')
                ch = getchar();

            array[i++] = ch;
        }

        array[i] = '\0';

        while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
            ch = getchar();

        printf("%s\n", array);
    }

    return 0;
}


I suggest you step through the code in a debugger to see where it's getting stuck.

Side note: getchar() returns int, and it may overflow char.  You should declare ch as an int.

Peter, consider what happens when a line feed is read via while(ch == ' ') ch = getchar();.

Consider also what happens to any letter that is read via while(ch == ' ') ch = getchar();.

Your code has:
while(ch == ' ')
    ch = getchar();

If ch is the space that was at the end of a line, the next character in the stream is a new-line character, so that sets ch to '\n'. Then the containing loop continues with the test in the while:
(ch = getchar()) != EOF
&& ch != '\n'
&& i < MAX_SIZE - 1)

Since the program already read the new-line character, that getchar seeks to read the first character of the next line. That is not in the stream buffer yet, so the computer has to read from the terminal to get it. Hence you must enter more input before the loop continues.
If you merely want to omit spaces from the output, simply do not add them to the array. Change array[i++] = ch; to if (ch != ' ') array[i++] = ch; and remove the while(ch == ' ') loop.


ch has a wrong type. It has to be int not char
Do not use getchar inside the loops without checking the error and border conditions (like '\n').

int main()
{
    char array[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
    int ch = 0;


    while(1)
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        while((ch = getchar()) != EOF  && ch != '\n'   && i < MAX_SIZE - 1)
        {
            if(islower(ch))
                ch = toupper(ch);
            else if(isupper(ch))
                ch = tolower(ch);

            if(ch == ' ') continue;

            array[i++] = ch;
        }

        array[i] = '\0';
        printf("\"%s\"\n", array);
    }
    return 0;
}


There are multiple problems:

the type of ch must be int for reliable detection of EOF.
when the user hits Enter, the first inner loop breaks but the '\n' has been read, and you enter the second inner loop that reads more bytes until it gets another '\n', which explains your observations.
if the user types more than 5 characters different from space and newline, the sixth one is consumed and lost.
the program does not stop at the end of file and goes into an infinite loop printing empty lines.

Here is a modified version:
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 6  //+1 space for the 0

int main(void)
{
    char array[MAX_SIZE];
    int ch = 0;

    while (ch != EOF) {
        size_t i = 0;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
            if (ch == ' ')
                continue;
            if (i >= MAX_SIZE - 1) {
                ungetc(ch, stdin);
                break;
            }
            if (islower(ch))
                ch = toupper(ch);
            else if (isupper(ch))
                ch = tolower(ch);

            array[i++] = ch;
        }
        array[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", array);
    }
    return 0;
}

